# Routing error using MVC on iis 5.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using .NET MVC 2 with Windows XP (IIS 5.1). I have set up wildcards per this [blog](http://www.ee99ee.com/blog/2009/02/08/how-to-get-aspnet-mvc-working-under-iis-51-on-windows-xp/).
The problem I run into is sometimes when I call some of my actions, they are returning 404 errors.  Here's how I'm calling them (using a button):

```
            <% using (Html.BeginForm("MyController", "MyAction")){ %>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <% } %>
```

I'm thinking it might have to do with my buttons, but I'm not sure. My actions are accepting Posts only. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Re: 404 errors:</strike>

Did you do all the fancy setup for the URL rewriting in MVC for IIS 5.1? I have not been able to get that to work correctly for me, so I ALWAYS debug to see my stuff ASP.NET MVC stuff on my XP Pro machine. When I deploy to the IIS 7 environment, I don't have any problems.

Re: Posts only:

Are you decorating the ActionResults with AcceptVerbs? If you decorate it with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` then that is the only verb that an action will allow.

Comment: yep. [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]

Comment: If you are decorating with that, then you can only Post to it.

Comment: You were correct. Don't know why I didn't see that before. Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm confused. It WAS working, and now it's back to a 404. Strange.